# inputAccessoryView like iOS Mail

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextfield, uikeyboard, inputaccessoryview

Mail on iOS 15 has a new inputAccessoryView that combines typing suggestions with other action buttons such as text formatting, attachments etc. By default the typing suggestions are displayed with an arrow at the right edge of the view:

[image: Typing suggestions + arrow at right edge]

Which when tapped reveals the other actions:

[image: Other actions revealed]

I've checked the inputAccessoryView documentation and also reviewed WWDC 2021 sessions but can't find anything new in this regard. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

First idea that comes to mind: create a similar input accessory of your own. You can use the UITextChecker system API to generate the suggestions, and since you create the view yourself, there shouldn't be any problem adding the arrow and switching to the other interface.

Edit: to be more clear, this involves listening to changes in the typed text using a delegate call like:

```
textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String)
```

Split the typed text so that you can isolate the currently typed word and pass this last word to UISpellChecker.